# Customising chapter, section, and subsection styles, positions, and fonts

Tags: sectioning

I would quite like to replicate the layout of chapter, and section headings shown in the sample image below
[image]

In the above image we have the start of a chapter with a new section ("Discrete Random Variables")

What method are available to customise the positioning, layout and fonts of chapter headings, section headings and so on?

For pages which are not chapter openings, the format is:

[image]

I am using the report document class in case it is relevant

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

% Font packages and settings %
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{Baskervaldx}
\usepackage[Baskervaldx,upint]{newtxmath}

% Document layout and appearence packages
\usepackage{titlesec}

% Packages for figures, schematics, diagrams, and drawings %
\usepackage{graphicx}\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,patterns,decorations,shapes.geometric}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Oh Chapter My Chapter}

        \section{Section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The tool of choice for standard classes is the `titlesec` package.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look! Can you suggest anywhere that as some working examples? Or would you be willing to knock up a short one in an answer?

Comment: Yes, if you post a minimal (complete code), I can help.

Comment: Thanks. I have added the basics of my code. I stripped away some of my other packages to prevent potential conflict.

Comment: A question: in your screen shot, the section is unnumbered. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes. It would be preferable to still have it appear in the table of contents though. I often find if I use `\section*{...}` the appearance looks how I want but I lose the entry in the TOC. If this is too far out of scope I can work on this aspect myself, or post/search a fresh question.

Comment: But you won't have numbered subsections, and so on? In others words, only chapters would be numbered?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I sometimes find that excessive section numbering is very cluttered. And it is sufficient for a simple section/subsection title. These would still appear in the TOC with corresponding pages numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way of making a similar layout:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

% Font packages and settings %
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{Baskervaldx}
\usepackage[Baskervaldx,upint]{newtxmath}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
% Document layout and appearence packages
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\bfseries\filcenter}{\large\textsc{\chaptername} \thechapter}{3ex}{\Large\MakeUppercase}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0ex}{6ex}

\titleformat{\section}[block]{\bfseries\filcenter}{}{0pt}{\large\textsc}
% Packages for figures, schematics, diagrams, and drawings %
\usepackage{graphicx}\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,patterns,decorations,shapes.geometric}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.pathreplacing}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

 \chapter{Oh Chapter! Where Art Thou?}
 \lipsum[11]

        \section{Section}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Fantastic thanks for taking the time!

Comment: Your solution seems to work perfectly and everything redners on the page as expected but I keep getting an error message of `[no file]:24: Undefined control sequence. [ \chapter{TITLE HERE}]` I can't find the bug at all! Any thoughts? It seems to be related to if I replace my font with `Baskervaldadf`

Comment: Could you post a minimal code reproducing the problem?

Comment: Of course! to avoid making the post very long, all I did was modify your example by changing `\bfseries` to `\Baskervaldadf`. If I remove the font specification completely it compiles without error and renders as expected.
`\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\Baskervaldx\filcenter}{\large\textsc{\chaptername} \thechapter}{3ex}{\Large\MakeUppercase}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0ex}{6ex}

\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Baskervaldx\filcenter}{}{0pt}{\large\textsc}`

Comment: I think I am probably specifying the font incorrectly. Seeing as I set the default font to be `\Baskervaldx` I guess the commands you developed for me inherit this -- so by removing the font specification I remove my error.

Comment: Where did you find the `\Baskervaldadf` command?

Comment: Again I think I am wrong with it's use but the manual is here: http://mirror.kumi.systems/ctan/fonts/baskervaldadf/doc/fonts/baskervald/baskervaldadf.pdf

Comment: Well, I know this documentation, but there's no `\Baskervaldadf` command. What are you trying to obtain exactly, with this command?

Comment: Ah, I've just realised my mistake. I mistook a command for a font style. I assumed `bfseries` was a specific font and not a command for a font style. Thanks again for your time, you helped me figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use the `memoir` class (a superset of the `book`, `report` and `article` classes then I think that the following might give what you are after.

```
% chapsecprob.tex SE 532267 change chapter and section styles

\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makechapterstyle{yourchapterstyle}{% % a slight modification to the thatcher chapterstyle
  \chapterstyle{thatcher}%
  \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}% Remove the rule
}

\setsecheadstyle{\scshape\centering} % section styling

\makepagestyle{yourpagestyle}        % page header/footer styling
  \makeevenfoot{yourpagestyle}{}{}{} % no even page footer
  \makeoddfoot{yourpagestyle}{}{}{}  % no odd page footer
  \makeevenhead{yourpagestyle}{\thepage}{\leftmark}{} % even page header
  \makeoddhead{yourpagestyle}{}{\leftmark}{\thepage}  % odd page header

\begin{document}
\chapterstyle{yourchapterstyle}
\pagestyle{yourpagestyle}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\chapter[Random variables and probability distributions]%
  [Random variables]%
  {Random variables and probability distributions}
% \chapter[for ToC][for header]{Title in document}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Discrete Random Variables}
\lipsum[2]
\section*{Unnumbered section}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Unnumbered section} % only if you want the unnumred section in the ToC
\lipsum[3]

\lipsum[4]

\clearpage
\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

Read the `memoir` documentation (`texdoc memoir`) for more information and change the above to suit your needs. I have concentrated on your layout not the use of fonts.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll also take a look -- you've even replicated the page numbering!! very nice!